# Printing class not working

Tags: python

I am new to python and can't figure this out.

I have a class like

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def greet(self):
        print('Hello', self.name)
```

And I try to print it using **print** but it prints

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x101fe9438>
```

Why does it not print the name and age?

Comment: 1. please rearrange your question - some of your code is not in the code environment. 
2. you may want to read about repr - https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: To get the name of the person object, do object_of_person.greet() or, you can also write print(object_of_person.name), print(object_of_person.age)

Comment: Thanks that fixed